# curl_init() fails silently in softaculous custom script

Tags: php, wordpress, softaculous

I am building a custom softaculous script that installs and activates a theme along with wordpress. To accomplish this, I need to make a call out of the softaculous install.php file:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/file.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

After attaching some debugging, I found that the curl_init() function was failing. I tried taking this code and putting directly into another file and calling it via web, which works great, but for some reason it fails when executed as part of a softaculous install.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you calling curl_init in a loop?

Comment: no, just once. I just need to execute the code in file.php out of the context of the current request so I can load all the wordpress stuff without breaking the SSL session.

Comment: And your php installation fully supports curl? Did you verify with `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Yes, If I take this same code and move it into a different php file, and call that directly, everything works.

Comment: Then something else is going on, and it's impossible to give an answer without more context.

Answer (score 1):

I am from the Softaculous team. Softaculous uses the 3rd party PHP binary while installing a script. Can you please check if cURL is enabled in the 3rd party PHP binary.

If you still face any issues please open a support ticket with us we will check it.